# Python Threading with Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I would like 3 Threads in Python to run for `n` seconds. I want to start them all at the same time and have them finish at the same time (within milliseconds). How do I do this?

`threading.Timer` only starts after the previous one has been completed.

Comment: In some cases, it may be hard to guarantee that they will actually finish within milliseconds of each other. For example, suppose the code calls out to a non-Python library that does not release the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). In such a case, the finish times for the threads may be staggered by at least the length of time needed to execute the library calls. You'd need to implement some sort of communication between the threads to synch them up before allowing them to finish. (Or, perhaps re-consider whether it's really *that* important for them to finish at the same time?)

Comment: It doesn't have to be even close to exactly. I said "within milliseconds" to mean that it doesn't have to be exactly 10 seconds. I wasn't saying "within milliseconds" as a constraint. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
import threading 
import time

class A(threading.Thread):
  def run(self):
     print "here", time.time()
     time.sleep(10)
     print "there", time.time()


if __name__=="__main__":
  for i in range(3):
     a = A()
     a.start()
```

prints:

```
here 1279553593.49
here 1279553593.49
here 1279553593.49
there 1279553603.5
there 1279553603.5
there 1279553603.5
```

Comment: See Dan's comment at the original post. This can't be guaranteed to finish (even sort-of) simultaneously (some threads might not receive CPU time, for instance). Also, using "sleep" isn't really practical, supposedly the threads should be doing something in the meantime...

Comment: @rbp: you're right, but the OP didn't indicate what each thread has to do - if one thread has much more work than the other, then I don't really see the point of the question... I think that as a practical solution, this probably answers the OP's needs (either way the threads will never finish "at the same time").